# Why are open(2) and close(2) split across different headers?

Tags: c, file-io, posix, system-calls

The header which contained `open(2)` is `fctnl.h` in the C standard library while `close(2)` is found in `unistd.h`. Both syscalls are inherently tied together and I can't think of any situation where I'd want to create a file descriptor and not close it again. In most other languages the logical equivalents of `open(2)` and `close(2)` are located in the same header, module or whatever the language uses.

Why is it that they are split between headers? Is there a technical explanation or some other logical reason or is it maybe for historical reasons?

Comment: Legacy. POSIX is a standard that grew from Unix and Unix-like systems. And Unix is *old*, well over 50 years. Things weren't so clear-cut in the olden days, and were added when- or where-ever needed. Then it just stuck, and changing would break a *lot* of applications.

Comment: I don't know the specific history of why what ended up in which header, but I'll point out that you use `close()` to close file descriptors created in other ways than just files opened via `open()`. For example, sockets (`socket()`), pipes (`pipe()`), shared memory (`shm_open`) and so on.

Comment: `open` is only one of the many functions that returns a file descriptor that you should close with `close`.

Comment: Some nitpicking as well: The headers `fcntl.h` and `unistd.h` are POSIX header files (coming from Unix and Unix-like systems). They are *not* part of the C standard library.

Comment: I'm not sure the two are tied together as much as you think they are. `open()` is specifically about opening files, and is only _one_ way to create a file descriptor. There are many other ways, such as `socket()`, `dup()`, `accept()`, etc. On the other hand, `close()` is a totally generic way of closing them. So declaring open in `fcntl.h` (file control) and close in `unistd.h` is not without merit.

Comment: `I can't think of any situation where I'd want to create a file descriptor and not close it again` Imagine you write a function that opens a file in calculated path. That sole function will not close the file descriptor, only open it, and return the fd.

Comment: > *I can't think of any situation where I'd want to create a file descriptor and not close it again* Specifically to `open()`: open a file, load another image with `exec()`. New image will have descriptor of opened file.

Comment: The `open()` call uses macros that were added to `<fcntl.h>`; the `close()` call doesn't need any extra macros, so it was placed in `<unistd.h>`.  Neither was declared in the days before POSIX — there was no need since they were functions returning `int` values, and there were no prototypes before 1989 (POSIX and Standard C are approximately the same age).  And POSIX invented the `O_CREAT` option to `open()` which makes it into a variadic function (2 or 3 arguments; the third is needed only when `O_CREAT` is specified).